# What is a BS Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property, english

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **BS Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| BS Words™ | Not BS Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| eagle | owl |
| boy | girl |
| gentleman | lady |
| ticket | pass |
| blow | blast |
| guarantee | assure |
| rectangle | square |
| hilarious | humorous |
| debate | argue |
| Sunday | Monday |

CSV version:

```
BS Words™, Not BS Words™
eagle, owl
boy, girl
gentleman, lady
ticket, pass
blow, blast
guarantee, assure
rectangle, square
hilarious, humorous
debate, argue
Sunday, Monday
```

These are not the only examples of BS Words™. **What is the special rule that BS Words™ conform to?**

---

Hint zone: A hint will be posted once a while

Hint 1:

> No politics involved.

Hint 2:

> Some of the letters are chosen, to form some kind of word.

Hint 3:

> The long form of BS that is related to this puzzle is included in a page of Wikipedia.

Hint 4:

> Actually one more tag should be added, but it will give out the answer. So I will add it later on.

Hint 5:

> The [video-games](/questions/tagged/video-games) tag should be added.

Hint 6:

> It is related to the characters in a video game.

Hint 7: (BIG)

> There will be more and more **BS Words™** from time to time, so I have to specify that the information to create this puzzle is taken on the day of puzzle creation, i.e. 16/5/2020.

Comment: Most of the words from the politicians are utter BS.

Comment: @rhsquared It is not about politics.

Comment: @rhssquared It's [not entirely their fault](https://youtu.be/T8QOE-IWo3I) that their answers are BS words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>(Oh, I should have spotted this connection so much sooner - my son is *obsessed* with the theme here!)</sub>

A "BS Word" is:

> A word which contains *all* of the letters from **the name of a 'Brawler' from the mobile video game [Brawl Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brawl_Stars)** made by Supercell (albeit not necessarily in the correct order).
>
>  To see this, a list of all Brawlers in the game can be found [here](https://brawlstars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Brawlers), and the names hidden within the BS Words are as follows:
>
>  **EAGL**E = GALE,
>  **BO**Y = BO,
>  **GEN**TL**E**MAN = GENE,
>  **TICK**ET = TICK,
>  **B**L**O**W = BO (again),
>  **G**UARA**N**T**EE** or GU**ARA**N**T**EE = GENE (again) or TARA,
>  R**E**CT**A**N**GL**E or **R**E**C**T**A**NG**L**E = GALE (again) or CARL,
>  HIL**AR**I**O**U**S** = ROSA (and since his release in November 2020 - *after* this puzzle was created - LOU can also be found among these letters),
>  D**EBA**TE = BEA,
>  **S**U**NDAY** = SANDY
>
>  In contrast, the words indicated as 'Not BS Words' do not contain the letters which make up the name of a Brawler.

This naturally explains the name given to these words too, since:

> The initials of 'Brawl Stars' are **BS**. Note as per Hint 7 that because new Brawlers are added to the game every few months or so, words which are not presently BS Words may become so one day - and this may include some of those words currently listed as 'Not BS Words'!

Comment: I play the game, and now I’m upset I looked at the answer right away instead of trying to solve it myself. I probably wouldn’t have thought of it anyways though!

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins It was TICKET that gave it away to me at long last - that one's perhaps the easiest to spot, but still you've got to recognise it for what it is. My lad was playing it at the same time I was trying to solve this for the umpteenth time, so something subconscious must have been going on!

Comment: Haha, I played about an hour ago. Still, BS *never* got me thinking Brawl Stars, good solve. Even though I’d consider myself one of the “hardcore” gamers on Brawl Stars, there’s almost no way I’d solve this myself. I’ve been playing since 2017 (before the global release!). I even changed my App Store location to Canada to get it years ago! I still play it to this day.

Comment: Tell your son the game used to be played vertically and see what he thinks of that!

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins That just blew his mind!

Comment: Probably not as much as you blew my mind with your answer. Barley’s super used to be focusable into 1 small group, and the damage stacked. Darryl used to be able to super across an entire heist arena so if you had Darryl and Barley on your team in heist, you basically won, as long as you were attacking because it used to be attack or defense.

Comment: Correct! I forgot to add hints after I forgot that I made this problem. But checkmark incoming!